# Unintended quotation marks appearing in grim file name

Tags: linux, escape-characters

I don't quite understand why I am getting some odd behavior trying to generate a screenshot file name when using grim/slurp.

If I do this:

```
grim -g "$(slurp)" "$HOME/screenshot-$(date).png"
```

I get:

```
screenshot-Sat 27 Jun 2020 06:02:36 PM EDT
```

Which is ok except that the time does not sort in my file folder. So, I tried this:

```
grim -g "$(slurp)" "$HOME/screenshot-$(date +\"%y%m%d_%T\").png"
```

But in that case I get this:

```
screenshot-"200627_19:35:39.png"
```

Can someone explain why quotation marks are appearing around the whole date string (none are in the expression), and how to elminate them?

Comment: You have literal quotes `\"` in your `date` format string...

Comment: you "escaped" the quote marks by using backslashes

Comment: Ok, I thought I had to escape them, but I guess not.

Comment: The $( .. ) syntax substitution has higher precedence than the outer quotes, so the quoting rules start afresh inside it. But I would have expected you to get `screenshot-"200627_19:35:39".png`.

Comment: Based on the comments, we're so used to knowing how it works to forget that it might not be obvious, like the comparison with backticks shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$()` creates a new quoting context, so you don't need to escape quotes inside it. That's one of the reasons why `$()` is preferred to ``` `` ```, in which mixing nesting and quotes would lead to a nightmare.

For comparison:

```
$ echo "screenshot-$(date +\"%y%m%d_%T\").png"
screenshot-"200701_14:56:19".png
$ echo "screenshot-`date +\"%y%m%d_%T\"`.png"
screenshot-200701_14:56:27.png
```

You can leave the backslashes out and just use `"screenshot-$(date +"%y%m%d_%T").png"`. Or, since `%` and the others aren't special, just leave the inner quotes out altogether:

```
$ echo "screenshot-$(date +%y%m%d_%T).png"
screenshot-200701_14:57:23.png
```

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for your examples! I actually tried to upvote what you have written a couple of times before I realized it was technically my answer :)

Comment: It is your answer, you provided the main point! I wouldn't have remembered how backticks work otherwise.

Comment: @ilkkachu That's the first sign of age: forgetting things, the next is: .... nah, I can't remember  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the backslashes. Not this:

<s>`grim -g "$(slurp)" "$HOME/screenshot-$(date +\"%y%m%d_%T\").png"`</s>

but this:

```
grim -g "$(slurp)" "$HOME/screenshot-$(date +"%y%m%d_%T").png"
```

But about your comment: *the time does not sort in my file folder*

I recommend you to use: FullYear - Moth - Day or `%Y%m%d_%T` or just `%F_%T`

With that format, text sorting works fine with dates.